# How to use Maven in Intellij to import dependencies

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am completely new to Maven, and I am trying to use it to import dependencies into my project. As a test, I am trying to import JUnit. I made a new class called `HelloWorldTest`, and added `import org.junit.runner.RunWith` to the top. The keyword `junit` is highlighted red. I do alt+enter, and select "Add Maven dependency", but that brings up a window that says "No results found."

I would expect JUnit is a fairly standard dependency, and that Maven would be able to find it for me. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

When I look at the "Search for artifact" tab, it seems like the only artifacts available are those starting alphabetically after "x". Could something be misconfigured? Do I need to clear a cache of some sort? I was able to import `xmlunit`, so for the artifacts that are there, things work correctly.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxwY4.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the pom.xml file that if there is following code snippet:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>junit</groupId>
 <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
 <version>4.11</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, maven won't fetch this dependency automatically.

Comment: Added that to my pom.xml, but it doesn't have any effect--when I do "Add Maven dependency", it still does not find junit.

Comment: That might be some problems with your network proxy, do u have any proxy setup on your env? If so, it requires more configurations.

Comment: Don't think so. Updated the original question--it seems like only certain artifacts are available. Not sure why this has happened...

Comment: Can you try with my configuration that i committed above? It's only for check if it works, because i am pretty sure that my configuration is correct.

Comment: Ah! You are correct. I was wrapping `<dependency>` in `<dependencyManagement><dependencies><dependency>...</dependency></dependencies></dependencyManagement>`, but the correct way is just `<dependencies><dependency>...</dependency></dependencies>`